# Why $\log(W(e^2))=2-W(e^2)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, lambert-w

While trying to solve $x+e^x=2$ I found two solutions:

$$x=\log(W(e^2))=2-W(e^2)$$

It is not at all obvious to me why the two solutions would represent the same number. How are the two related?

Any help to make this more intuitive or insightful would be appreciated!

Comment: $x+e^x$ is an increasing function. In particular, $$x+e^x=2$$ has at most one solution.

Comment: What is $W$? And how did you come to this?

Comment: In general, $\log(W(e^x)) = x - W(e^x)$ which follows from the identity $e^{W(x)} = \frac{x}{W(x)}$ by plugging in $e^x$ in place of $x$ and rearranging slightly.

Comment: @Mr.Newman $W$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with the second equality:

\begin{align}
x&=2-W(e^2)\\
\implies 2-x &= W(e^2)\\
\implies (2-x)e^{2-x} &= e^2\\
\implies 2e^{2}e^{-x} - xe^{2}e^{-x} &= e^{2}\\
\implies 2e^{-x} - xe^{-x} &= 1\\
\implies 2 - x &= e^{x}
\end{align}

Now, with the first equality:

\begin{align}
x &= \log(W(e^2))\\
\implies e^x &= W(e^2)\\
\implies e^xe^{e^x} &= e^{2}\\
\implies e^{x+e^{x}} &= e^{2}\\
\implies x+e^{x} &= 2\\
\implies 2 - x &= e^{x}
\end{align}

and so we see that the two solutions are consistent.